# To draw monomial matricies

Tags: amsmath, arrays

Need the LaTex code of the fallowing figure given below:[image]

Comment: Shahnawaz, you have now asked 7 questions on the site, and every one of them simply gives a picture and a request for code. You need to show some effort in solving the problems you pose and post minimal documents showing the parts you are having trouble with.  Then people will be much more inclined to help you.

Comment: \newsavebox{\smallblockbox}
\newenvironment{smallblockarray}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\smallblockbox}
  \scriptsize$\begin{blockarray}}
 {\end{blockarray}$\end{lrbox}%
  \raisebox{-1ex}[\dimexpr\height-1ex][\dimexpr\depth-1ex]{\usebox{\smallblockbox}}}
[\
\bigoplus_P\xrightarrow{
\begin{smallblockarray}{lc}
   {\cdots} {\bf a}_p {\cdots} \\
    \begin{block}{[c]l}
    {.} & {\vdots}\\
    \lambda_{pq} & {\bf a}_q\\
   {.} & \{vdots}\\
     \end{block}
 \end{smallblockarray}
}
\bigoplus_P
    
\]

Comment: This is what i have done so far-Alan Munn

Comment: Please edit your *question* and post a *complete* minimal document, not a code fragment.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No fancy package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\bigoplus_{q} S(-\mathbf{a}_{q})
\xrightarrow{
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}}
    & \cdots \; \mathbf{a}_{p} \; \cdots \\[-1ex]
    \begin{matrix} \vdots \\ \mathbf{a}_{q} \\ \vdots \end{matrix} &
    \begin{bmatrix} & & \\ & \lambda_{qp} & \\ & & \end{bmatrix}
  \end{array}
}
\bigoplus_{p} S(-\mathbf{a}_{p})
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For ease of readability of the code, consider constructing the two components of this expression separately. First store the matrix inside a box (say `\matrixbox`) and then `\usebox` it as part of the larger expression:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,kbordermatrix,graphicx}

\newsavebox{\matrixbox}

\begin{document}

% Store matrix
\begin{lrbox}{\matrixbox}
$\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}\kbordermatrix{
  & \rotatebox{90}{$\vdots$} & \ \mathbf{a}_p & \rotatebox{90}{$\vdots$} \\
  \vdots & & & \\
  \mathbf{a}_q & & \lambda_{qp} & \\
  \vdots & & &
}$
\end{lrbox}

\[
  \bigoplus_q S(-\mathbf{a}_q)
  \xleftarrow{\usebox{\matrixbox}}
  \bigoplus_p S(-\mathbf{a}_p)
\]

\end{document}
```

You can use any multitude of ways of constructing the matrix. I used [`kbordermatrix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/kbordermatrix).

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\newsavebox{\smallblockbox}
\newenvironment{smallblockarray}
{\begin{lrbox}{\smallblockbox}
\normalsize$\begin{blockarray}}
 {\end{blockarray}$\end{lrbox}%
\raisebox{-1ex}[\dimexpr\height-1ex][\dimexpr
\depth-1ex]{\usebox{\smallblockbox}}}
 \begin{document}
\[
{\bigoplus}_p S(-{\bf a}_p)
\xrightarrow{
\begin{smallblockarray}{lcrr}
\cdots & {\bf a}_p & \cdots &\\
\begin{block}{[ccr]l}
& & & \vdots\\
&  \lambda_{pq} & &{\bf a}_q \\
& & & \vdots\\
  \end{block}
\end{smallblockarray}
}{\bigoplus}_p S(-{\bf a}_p)
\]
\end{document}
```